# How can i show one random word from a String every 10 seconds?

Tags: java, android

I'm developing a simple app, and I want to show a random word from a string array every 10 seconds, but I don't know how I can do it. This is my code for the words.

```
public void nuevaPalabra(){
    final String[] palabras = {"prueba", "electricidad", "sonido", "fruta", "camisa"};

    int random = (int) (Math.random() * 4);

    palabraaleatoria.setText(palabras[random]);
}
```

I apologize if it is a stupid question but I have started studying android recently and I do not know much, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Timer` to cancel `timer` use `timer.cancel()`

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();

        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Random random = new Random();
                final String[] palabras = {"prueba", "electricidad", "sonido", "fruta", "camisa"};
                final int rand = random.nextInt(palabras.length);
                palabraaleatoria.setText(palabras[rand]);
            }
        };

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, new Date(), 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using a Runnable with a random integer. I imagine it would look something like this:

```
    String[] palabras = { "prueba", "electricidad","sonido", "fruta", "camisa" };
    Random rand = new Random();
    Runnable name = new Runnable() {
      @Override
       public void run() {
           Int i = rand.nextInt(palbras.legnth()) + 1;
           palabraaleatoria.setText(palabras[i]);

           handler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
       }
    };
```

Comment: I think you should add 2 things, `handler` instantiation and a way to stop it

Comment: Oh okay. I was a little confused between Timers, and Runnables since I had not created one in a while. Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping **"palabraaleatoria"**  is an textview I've also set text change after 4 sec It'll do what you want.

**(int) (Math.random()*4)** -  this method create random number between 0 to 4 where 4 is the max as your array length.

**palabraaleatoria** - hoping it is textview and set a runnable to a view with 4 sec delay millis.

```
palabraaleatoria.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            palabraaleatoria.setText(palabras[(int) (Math.random()*4)]);

            palabraaleatoria.postDelayed(this, 4000);
        }
    });
```